# Mount SMB: mount error(40): Too many levels of symbolic links - How to debug and resolve?

Tags: mount, smb

running the command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<IP>/Folder /mnt/Folder -o username=some_user,password="some_pass",gid=<ID>,uid=<ID>
```

Gives the error:

```
mount error(40): Too many levels of symbolic links
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

This started after rebooting the machine - after updating OS packages (arch linux), including the kernel. I have no clue why this started or is happening - I am a bit in the dark.

**My question is**: How can I debug this, i.e. find what is causing the "Too many levels of symbolic links" and ultimately resolve it? Any ideas, tricks, which can get me closer to resolving this?

I am trying to run `sudo find -L -xtype l` in `\`, trying to cause it to report `"Too many levels of symbolic links"` but this command takes forever and is also generating other kind of messages which is making it hard to work with.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to mount `Folder` back in on itself, on the same machine? Perhaps the folder on the source system has gone bad in some way. You'll have to get on the source system to find out.

Comment: Thanks Bib. Initially I thought that as well: that the remote network folder might have the issue. However I tried mounting the network `Folder` in some other laptop I have that runs Ubuntu and that one works fine. So this is why I am focusing on my system. The destination folder in my system is of course empty.

Comment: Well, you could always run `strace -f mount.cifs  //<ip>/...` and see what it's doing.

Comment: Cannot find something unfortunately:
`mount("//192.xxx.xxx.xxx/Test", ".", "cifs", 0, "ip=192.xxx.xxx.xxx,unc=\\\\192.xxx."...) = -1 ELOOP (Too many levels of symbolic links)
capset({version=_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid=268127}, {effective=1<<CAP_SYS_ADMIN, permitted=1<<CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|1<<CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|1<<CAP_SYS_ADMIN, inheritable=0}) = 0
write(2, "mount error(40): Too many levels"..., 51mount error(40): Too many levels of symbolic links
) = 51`

I have even created an empty network drive `Test` to make sure the remote folder is not the problem.

Comment: I went back one kernel version, from `linux-5.17.1.arch1-1-x86_64` to `linux-5.16.16.arch1-1-x86_64` and it works again now.

Comment: It seems this has become a known issue for people using Synology. Here is the thread in arch linux forum https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=275262. A temp fix could be to disable `Control Panel -> File services -> SMB -> Advanced Settings -> Enable MSDFS VFS module` for kernels >=5.17